# How do I use wget to download a list of files from different URLs on the same site and store the files in the same folder structure as the URL?

Tags: linux, wget

I have a list of files I need to download at different URLs on the same site.

Using the command:

```
wget --http-user:user@domain.name --http-password:password -i download.txt
```

The files download to the current local path OK, but I'd like to create the structure where the files came from.

The download.txt file has the full path to the files I want to download:

- `http://site1.domain.name/URL1/XX1/XXX1/filename1.xxx`
- `http://site1.domain.name/URL2/XX2/XXX2/filename2.xxx`
- `http://site1.domain.name/URL2/XX 3/XX X3/file name 3.xxx`
- and so on

Is there a way to do this with wget and a script of some sort? (that will create the structure where the files came from)

The site is hosted on a Windows Server IIS/SharePoint 2003 farm. So the files I'm downloading are not accessible through the filesystem on the site, only via URL.

(Note: I tried Httrack, it will do the entire site structure with files (days and days to run) but no matter what I try... I get a 401 unauthorized when trying to download only the files in download.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wget --http-user:user@domain.name --http-password:password -i download.txt -x
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you highlighted that you're adding `-x` and what this does.

Comment: Outstanding!! Just what I was looking for. Thank you very much!! I was so close, but yet so very far from getting this. Thanks again. BTW.... the --http-user: should be --http-user=, as well as the --http-password= (rather than a : colon)